# How do I run a custom function ONLY the first time a user scrolls to a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**The problem:**

I have a fancy looping image carousel that needs to start—from a specific first slide—when the user scrolls to a certain div. It should NEVER restart if the user scrolls up/down and back to that div.

I can only currently get it to start when the user scrolls to the div—and then it gets screwed up when you scroll away and back to it, which I assume is because the function starts running again.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. User scrolls to certain div
2. Fancy image carousel animation function runs
3. If user scrolls up/down and back to the div, the animation function never starts again.

**My (anonymized, sorry guys!) code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/h8pqW/

HTML

```
<p class="scroll_down">Scroll down...</p>

<div class="animation_container">You should get an alert only once here—the first time you scroll to this div.</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll_down {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.animation_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

jQuery

```
// The fancy function for my animations
function doSomeComplicatedStuff() {
  alert("...and here's where the complicated animations happen!");
}

// The function to check if div.animation_container is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

// If div.animation_container is scrolled into view, run the fancy function
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView('.animation_container')) {
    run_once(function() {
      doSomeComplicatedStuff();
    });
  }
});

// The function that's supposed to make sure my fancy function will only run ONCE, EVER
function run_once( callback ) {
  var done = false;
  return function() {
    if ( !done ) {
      done = true;
      return callback.apply( this, arguments );
    }
  };
}
```

Apologies for the script clearly written by a visual designer. Let me know if the question isn't clear enough from the anonymized code.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to not be working

Comment: Sorry, I was trying so many different things to achieve what I wanted that I left some broken code in there. I guess it didn't match up to what I described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move that `done` variable into a global?

```
var firstScroll = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView('.animation_container') && !firstScroll) {
      doSomeComplicatedStuff();
  }
});

function doSomeComplicatedStuff() {

    firstScroll = true;        

    // Your code here
}
```

This way, the first time `isScrolledIntoView` returns true, the `doComplicatedStuff` function immediately flips the boolean `firstScroll` that stops subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this

```
// The fancy function for my animations
var alreadyRun = false;
function doSomeComplicatedStuff() {
    alert("...and here's where the complicated animations happen!");
}

// The function to check if div.animation_container is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

// If div.animation_container is scrolled into view, run the fancy function
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView('.animation_container') && !alreadyRun) {
      doSomeComplicatedStuff();
      alreadyRun = true;
  }
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8pqW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Put that done variable into the global scope. Else it is redefined again and again every time that `run_once()` is called. A better approach would be adding a first parameter to that function to identify which action is ran or not (`function run_once(identifier,callback) { if(!done[identifier]) { run function and set done[identifier] to true; }`)
2. Remove that `return function()` from `run_once()`
3. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/at8D5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h8pqW/2/

Basically, you were running `run_once` every time the condition was met, so it was creating a new `done` variable.  I moved the `run_once` call out into the `doSomeComplicatedStuff` declaration, converting that to a method that will only run once.

```
// The fancy function for my animations
var doSomeComplicatedStuff = run_once(function () {
    alert("...and here's where the complicated animations happen!");
});
```

---

Here is a more performant alternative that does not require the use of a `run_once` helper: http://jsfiddle.net/h8pqW/3/

In this example, I simply unbind the `scroll` event as soon as the function is called.  This will prevent the page from continuing to try to run the function each time the user scrolls.

```
// If div.animation_container is scrolled into view, run the fancy function
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView('.animation_container')) {
    doSomeComplicatedStuff();
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
  }
});
```